# PHP Explode and updata data to each colomn in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have a form where I want a user to upload one or more images. I've used only one file field for this. The issue is when I submit the form only the "itemImageOne" field will be update. But the `echo part( echo $pieces[0], echo $pieces[1] )` is shows the correct result. Bellow is part of my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
@ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');

/* * *********************************************** */
// database constants
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'ibs');

$dboptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);

try {
  $DB = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ':host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $dboptions);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
  die;
}

if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
  // include resized library
  //require_once('./php-image-magician/php_image_magician.php');
  $msg = "";
  $pieces = "";
  $valid_image_check = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/bmp");
  if (count($_FILES["user_files"]) > 0) {
    $folderName = "uploads/";

    //$sql = "UPDATE module_course SET itemImage='$filename' WHERE id=1";
    //$sql = "UPDATE SET module_course(itemImage) VALUES (:img)";
    //$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) {

      if ($_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] <> "") {

        $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
        // if valid image type then upload
        if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) {

          $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
          $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
          $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;
          $filepath = $folderName . $filename;




        $pieces = explode(" ", $filename);
        $imageOne = $pieces[0];
        $imageTwo = $pieces[1];
        echo $pieces[0]."<br/>"; // piece1
        echo $pieces[1]."<br/>"; // piece2

        $sql = "UPDATE module_course  SET itemImageOne = $imageOne, itemImageTwo = $date WHERE id='1'";
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);



          if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filepath)) {
            $emsg .= "Failed to upload <strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong>. <br>";
            $counter++;
          } else {
            $smsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> uploaded successfully. <br>";


            /*             * ****** insert into database starts ******** */
            try {
              $stmt->bindValue(":img", $filename);
              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->rowCount();
              if ($result > 0) {
                // file uplaoded successfully.
              } else {
                // failed to insert into database.
              }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
              $emsg .= "<strong>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</strong>. <br>";
            }
            /*             * ****** insert into database ends ******** */
          }
        } else {
          $emsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> not a valid image. <br>";
        }
      }
    }


    $msg .= (strlen($smsg) > 0) ? successMessage($smsg) : "";
    $msg .= (strlen($emsg) > 0) ? errorMessage($emsg) : "";
  } else {
    $msg = errorMessage("You must upload atleast one file");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: try `$sql = "UPDATE module_course  SET itemImageOne = $imageOne, itemImageTwo= $imageTwo WHERE id=1";`

Comment: and check `itemImageTwo` filed type as well

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply... 
$sql = "UPDATE module_course SET itemImageOne = $imageOne, itemImageTwo= $imageTwo WHERE id=1"
this gives me "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=1' at line 1. "

Comment: check answer below

Comment: share `print_r($_FILES["user_files"]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UPDATE module_course 
SET itemImageOne = $imageOne, itemImageTwo =  $imageTwo
WHERE id = '1'; # Changed
```

---

Changed - **Edit 01**

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("UPDATE module_course 
SET itemImageOne = ?, itemImageTwo =  ? 
WHERE id = 1");


$stmt->bindValue(1, $imageOne, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $imageTwo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

> Error Bcz of you are binding one parameter `$stmt->bindValue(":img", $filename);`

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE module_course SET itemImageOne = $imageOne, itemImageTwo =  $imageTwo WHERE id = '1'";
This gives me Syntax error.. :(

Comment: 'itemImageOne' field is been updated with "$imageTwo" value. and 'itemImageTwo' field is still empty in db. Now there is no Syntax errors... :)

Comment: `print_r($pieces)` and post the data

Comment: (
    [0] =&gt; 724245_1466323251.png
)
Array
(
    [0] =&gt; 903718_1466323251.png
)

Comment: check you database filed type

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `module_course` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemTitle` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `itemImageOne` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `itemImageTwo` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lineOne` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;